# Nexmo SMS api sending text with out body text

Tags: c#, .net, sms, vonage

I have a calledback method registered at Nexmo.

And I am having my action method hit by Nexmo when message is received.

But I am not getting message text and timestamp.

I am getting only `messageId`, Sender and receiver number in response

following is my code

```
      SMS.SMSRequest r = new SMS.SMSRequest();           
        r.to = "number";

        r.from = Configuration.Instance.Settings["a"];
        r.body = "Testing";
        r.text = "Testing";          

        Nexmo.Api.Request.Credentials c = new Nexmo.Api.Request.Credentials();
        c.ApiKey = "Key";
        c.ApiSecret = "key";
        c.ApplicationId = "ID";
        c.ApplicationKey = "XYZ";
       // r.message_class = "1";
        r.type = "text"; 


        r.callback = "http://www.eurosoftsms.co.uk/inbound/SMSInbound"; 
           var x=  Nexmo.Api.SMS.Send(r,c);
```

The result of `r.Send(..)` with status `0` means Its `OK`

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to [Nexmo's documentation](https://developer.nexmo.com/messaging/sms/guides/delivery-receipts), you shouldn't expect to get *message text* as part of the delivery receipt. The receipt *does* contain a timestamp, but note that the field's name is "message-timestamp". The problem is probably in your code that handles the callback, not the code that you posted which *sends* a message.